# UTF 8 (unicode) not working

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I made the mistake in generating my tables with the standard collation.
After switching to utf8 german letters are not displayed correctly.

I already made followging steps with no effect:

In Header:

```
meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"
```

After mysqli_connect:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
```

I changed all tables/fields to UTF8_unicode_ci.

What else should i do, to make this work? Really appreciate your help!
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
ok i got it:

Instead of:

```
mysqli_set_charset('utf8', $con);
```

i have to use:

```
mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Make sure everything is set up correctly as explained in the linked post. Then make sure new data works correctly. If old data already in the database doesn't work, you have messed up the changeover. Without more details it's hard to say what exactly went wrong.

Comment: shouldn't mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con); be mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8'); as you seem to be using mysqli..?

Comment: i tryed mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8'); with no effect.

Comment: try the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: would it help to export all field-data and import it into new tables?

Comment: ok i got it: mysqli_set_charset('utf8', $con); was wrong :) it should be mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8'); thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you are selecting or inserting data from or into database execute this query before every thing.

```
$query = "SET NAMES UTF8";
```

Comment: i put mysqli_query('SET NAMES UTF8'); before the result query with no effect.

Comment: whats your database charset ? is that utf8_general_ci ?

Comment: ok i got it: mysqli_set_charset('utf8', $con); was wrong :) it should be mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8'); thanks!!!